# Quantum computing and string theory: which path I may want to pursue first?

Tags: phd, physics, education

I'm an undergraduate physics student waiting for responses from graduate programs I applied to. I apologize if this question is slightly off-topic for physics SE, but I really want to hear some advice about the path I should pursue first to achieve my long-term goal.

I applied to Ph.D. programs in quantum information, as well as master's programs in mathematical physics, with a focus on string theory. I'm fascinated with the prospect of solving questions in fundamental physics through quantum computing. Recently I've been reading about [some research](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.06573) that combined these two fields.

My undergraduate study and research experiences introduced me to the basics of quantum mechanics and quantum simulation. I think the PhD program would definitely allow me to deepen my understanding of this field. However, I don't have a very strong background in mathematical physics and haven't been introduced to string theory. So I'm worried if there's no relevant course in PhD program, whether I would still have a chance to learn about string theory.

I would really appreciate it if anyone could give me some advice about how I can connect quantum computing with fundamental physics, or the path I should pursue first in this case.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we can't answer it for you. The answer depends on your interests and your aptitude. Talk to an advisor if you can. Both those subjects call for deep mathematics.

Comment: It would certainly depend somewhat on the nature of the program and the faculty available (if nobody there has string theory expertise it would be quite challenging), as well as your own aptitude and background. To gauge the latter, I would encourage you to have a look at Zwiebach's "A first course in string theory" or maybe the more advanced book by Becker, Becker, and Schwarz.

Comment: @Anyon Thank you!!